# Why does mysqli_num_rows() needs to expect parameter 1 to be mysqli_result,boolean given in...?

Tags: php, database, wampserver

I'm getting problem in one of my php files in wampserver. I have 3 php files named as **initial, registration and confirmation**.

Initial and registration php files are working accordingly.
However my 3rd file confirmation is not.My table name is "user_information".

Here is the code:

**initial.php**

```
<?php

$db_name = "myappdb";
$mysql_user = "root";
$mysql_pass = "";
$server_name = "localhost";

$con = mysqli_connect($server_name, $mysql_user, $mysql_pass, $db_name);
if (!$con) {
    echo"Error in connection try again..." . mysqli_connect_error();
} else {
    echo"<h3>Database is successfully connected!...</h3>";
}
?>
```

**registration.php**

```
<?php

require'initial.php';
$name = "angelina";
$user_name = "tom";
$user_pass = "cruise123";

$sql_query = "insert into user_information    values('$name','$user_name','$user_pass');";

if (mysqli_query($con, $sql_query)) {
    echo"<h3> Data is successfully inserted...</h3>";
} else {
    echo"Data Insertion is wrong..." . mysqli_error($con);
}
?>
```

**confirmation.php**

```
<?php

require'initial.php';
$user_name = "tom";
$user_pass = "cruise123";


$sql_query = "select name from user_informtion where user_name = '" . mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $user_name) . "' and user_pass =      '" . mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $user_pass) . "' ";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql_query);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    $name = $row["name"];
    echo"<h3>Hello welcome" . $name . "</h3>";
} else {
    echo"No information is available...";
}
?>
```

And I dont know why am getting this error:

> Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in.

Please help me on this.

Comment: try this -> select name from user_informtion where user_name='$user_name' and user_pass ='$user_pass';"

Comment: Your query has issue : like clause works with '%$user_name%', or you need to use '='

Comment: need space between `like'$user_name'` and here  `like'$user_pass'`

Comment: Your query is not returning a result set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `"="` instead of `LIKE` and used `mysqli_real_escape_string()` for preventing sql injection.

Replace:

```
$sql_query="select name from user_informtion where user_name like'$user_name' and user_pass like'$user_pass';";
```

With this:

```
$sql_query="select name from user_informtion where user_name = '".mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $user_name)."' and user_pass = '".mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $user_pass)."' ";
```

Comment: ok, I have used mysql_real_escape_string() for preventing sql injection.

Comment: Right now you are mixing mysql and mysqli in your code!!

Comment: am getting this error now: Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in ..

Comment: @Saty i have updated ans. Now using mysqli_real_escape_string() instead of mysql_real_escape_string().

Comment: another error amit :/ :Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysql_reali_escape_string() in ...

Comment: Check spelling of `mysql_reali_escape_string` read http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php

Comment: angelina its mysqli_real_escape_string not mysql_reali_escape_string. check the updated ans

Comment: Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysql_reali_escape_string(), is this error solved or not?

Comment: So getting this error now: Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given ??

Comment: yes 4 errors :Warning: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given in and Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in and Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in...amit

Comment: I gor the first error again:
if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0) am getting error here: 
Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result.

Comment: i have updated the confirmation.php code above as you said amit. still there is error.

Comment: The problem is your query returned false meaning there was an error in your query. After your query you could do the following:

Comment: after this line: $result=mysqli_query($con,$sql_query);

Comment: place this line:  if (!$result) { die(mysqli_error($con)); }    after this line: $result=mysqli_query($con,$sql_query);

Comment: let me know the output

Answer (score 0):

You have Error in your query on the **confirmation.php** page.

Your Query :

```
 $sql_query="select name from user_informtion where user_name like'$user_name' and user_pass like'$user_pass';";
```

If you want to use **like** clause then change your query to :

```
 $sql_query="select name from user_informtion where user_name like '%$user_name%' and user_pass like '%$user_pass%'";
```

But I would suggest you to use **'='**:

```
 $sql_query="select name from user_informtion where user_name ='".$user_name."' and user_pass = '".$user_pass."'";
```

Comment: Better to  suggest `bind statement` for preventing sql injection!!

Comment: Yes it can be done, but I only solved the issue that was being faced. Even we can suggest `mysql_real_escape_string`

Comment: @Nehal: it is giving me an other error : Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in...

Comment: @angelina are your values correctly inserted in DB through `insert` query

Comment: @angelina, I've already mention the changes that amit Rajput has updated in his answer I guess. So just your query